# Django url dispatcher and implicit namespace resolution

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm using django 1.4 on a project, and I want to use a template across the views of many apps. My urls.py looks like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^canvas/', include('canvas.urls', namespace="canvas")),
    url(r'^checkin/', include('checkin.urls', namespace="checkin")),
    url(r'^show/', include('facebook_tab.urls', namespace="show")),
```

My canvas/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from canvas.views import AllShowsView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^shows/$', AllShowsView.as_view(), name='shows'),
)
```

My facebook_tab/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from facebook_tab.views import AllShowsView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^shows/$', AllShowsView.as_view(), name='shows'),    
)
```

And I would like to use a template in such a way that I don't have to refer to the current namespace when using `{% url shows %}`.

I tried passing current_app to the Context dictionary with no success. Also it doesn't work when I try to do something like `reverse("shows", current_app="canvas")`. Official documentation is not quite clear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've finally done was using `url from future` as @lalo suggested, and adding both app and instance namespacing to my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^canvas/', include('canvas.urls', app_name="myapp", namespace="canvas")),
url(r'^checkin/', include('checkin.urls', app_name="myapp", namespace="checkin")),
url(r'^show/', include('facebook_tab.urls', app_name="myapp", namespace="facebook_tab")),
```

Then, from my views I set my current_app as:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, context, current_app="canvas")
```

And from my generic template:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'myapp:shows'%}
```

That last url would resolve to `'canvas:shows'` or `'facebook_tab:shows'` depending on the namespace set on `current_app`.

I read the official docs and I don't already get the difference between application namespace and instance namespace clearly, but I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Importing `url` from future in your template should work:

```
 #At the top of the template
 {% load url from future %}

 #Somewhere in your template
 {% url "canvas:shows" %}.
```

See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces
and 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url